Does Bloc Rebuild (BlocBuilder) The Whole Widget Tree When New State emitted?
I encountered an issue when I wrapped my MaterialApp widget in a BlocBuilder. I expected the entire widget tree to rebuild whenever a new state was emitted. However, I noticed that some widgets didn’t rebuild as expected.
Here’s a simplified example:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MyCubit, MyState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: state.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Hello, world!')),
    );
  }
}

In this setup:

When the isDarkMode state changes, the MaterialApp rebuilds with the new theme.
However, MyHomePage and its child widgets (e.g., Text('Hello, world!')) don’t rebuild, even though I expected the whole tree to respond to the state change.

What I Tried
To solve the problem, I wrapped the specific widgets that didn’t rebuild (e.g., MyHomePage) in another BlocBuilder, like this:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MyCubit, MyState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text(state.isDarkMode ? 'Dark Mode' : 'Light Mode')),
          body: Center(child: Text(state.isDarkMode ? 'Dark Mode On' : 'Light Mode On')),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

This approach worked, but now I’m wondering:

Is the reason some widgets didn’t rebuild initially because they were marked as const?
Or is it because BlocBuilder only rebuilds its immediate children, and deeper widgets are unaffected?
Is wrapping widgets in multiple BlocBuilders the best practice, or is there a better way to handle this?

I’d appreciate insights or recommendations!

Does BlocBuilder Rebuild The Whole Widget Tree?
No, BlocBuilder doesn't rebuild the entire widget tree. Here's how it actually works:
1. How Widget Rebuilding Works:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: state.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          home: const MyHomePage(), // const is fine here!
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Widgets will rebuild only when:

They use Theme.of(context)
They use BlocBuilder and depend on state
They're not marked as const and depend on changing state

2. Best Practice Implementation:
// 1. App Level (Theme Configuration)
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: state.isDarkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// 2. Home Page (Using Theme)
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Uses Theme.of(context) - will update automatically
        title: Text(
          'Theme Demo',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // Theme-dependent widget (uses Theme.of(context))
          Card(
            child: Text(
              'Theme dependent text',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
            ),
          ),

          // State-dependent widget (uses BlocBuilder)
          const ThemeStatusText(),

          // Theme toggle button
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => context.read<ThemeCubit>().toggleTheme(),
            child: const Text('Toggle Theme'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// 3. State-dependent widget
class ThemeStatusText extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThemeStatusText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Text(
          'Current Theme: ${state.isDarkMode ? 'Dark' : 'Light'}',
       
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Key Points:
1. For theme changes:

Use Theme.of(context) for automatic updates
Keep const for static widgets
No need for multiple BlocBuilders

2. For state-dependent content:

Use BlocBuilder when you need state access
Remove const if widget needs state updates

For actions:

Use context.read() for state changes (like button presses)

Remember:

BlocBuilder only rebuilds widgets that depend on state
Theme changes propagate through Theme.of(context)
const widgets won't rebuild (use when content is static)
Multiple BlocBuilders aren't needed for theme changes

This approach ensures:

Efficient rebuilding
Clean, maintainable code
Proper theme handling
Optimal performanc

Simple Guide:
class ThemeStatusText extends StatelessWidget {
const ThemeStatusText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print('ThemeStatusText rebuilt!'); // Debug print
  return Text('Hello');
}
}

// Usage Examples:
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      // 1. Won't Rebuild ❌
      const ThemeStatusText(),

      // 2. Will Rebuild with Theme ✅
      const ThemeStatusText2(),

      // 3. Will Rebuild with State ✅
      const ThemeStatusText3(),

      // 4. Will Rebuild with Both ✅
      const ThemeStatusText4(),
    ],
  );
}
}

// Theme Dependent
class ThemeStatusText2 extends StatelessWidget {
const ThemeStatusText2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Text(
    'Hello',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, // Makes it rebuild!
  );
}
}

// State Dependent
class ThemeStatusText3 extends StatelessWidget {
const ThemeStatusText3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(  // Makes it rebuild!
    builder: (context, state) {
      return Text('Hello');
    },
  );
}
}

// Both Theme & State
class ThemeStatusText4 extends StatelessWidget {
const ThemeStatusText4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<ThemeCubit, ThemeState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      return Text(
        'Hello',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, // Both make it rebuild!
      );
    },
  );
}
}

const ThemeStatusText()                    // ❌ No rebuild
const ThemeStatusText() + Theme.of()       // ✅ Rebuilds
const ThemeStatusText() + BlocBuilder      // ✅ Rebuilds
const ThemeStatusText() + Both            // ✅ Rebuilds

Whatever is below BlocBuilder will be rebuild. Solution:: Wrap whatever items requires rebuild with BlocBuilder. There can be more than one BlocBuilder in the same widget tree.
Also you can can control rebuild using buildWhen parameter in blocbuilder
